# method called after release() exception unable to resume with android camera

Tags: java, android, exception, callback, camera

While developing a camera app I've encountered an exception that only happened when I switch to other app (`onPause()` for my app).

```
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Native Method)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Camera.java:357)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at com.sora.cbir.yuki.image.leaf.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:32)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:551)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:213)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:4075)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:742)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:742)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:742)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:742)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:858)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1995)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
01-15 17:22:15.017: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I did some research and found out that I need to add

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
```

as a workaround for Android's camera stack

my `onPause()` now looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try
    {    
        // release the camera immediately on pause event   
        //releaseCamera();
         mCamera.stopPreview(); 
         mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
         mCamera.release();
         mCamera = null;

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and my `onResume()`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    try
    {
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        //mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(Imageupload.this, mCamera);//set preview
        preview.addView(mPreview);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}   
}
```

and finally my `getCameraInstance()` method:

```
public Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera camera = null;
    try {
        camera = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    //mPreviewSize = getBestPreviewSize(parameters, wt, ht);
    //mPictureSize = getBestPictureSize(parameters, wt, ht);
    //Shift W & H => if camera rotates 90 deg

    mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(parameters, wt, ht); //original => wt,ht
    mPictureSize = getOptimalPictureSize(parameters, wt, ht); //original => wt,ht

    Log.d("CAMERA", "SCREEN RESOLUTION H: "+ht);
    Log.d("CAMERA", "SCREEN RESOLUTION W: "+wt);

    Log.d("CAMERA", "PREVIEW RESOLUTION H: "+mPreviewSize.height);
    Log.d("CAMERA", "PREVIEW RESOLUTION W: "+mPreviewSize.width);

    Log.d("CAMERA", "PICTURE RESOLUTION H: "+mPictureSize.height);
    Log.d("CAMERA", "PICTURE RESOLUTION W: "+mPictureSize.width);
    //set preview size based on device screen
    parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
    //set picture size based on device screen
    parameters.setPictureSize(mPictureSize.width, mPictureSize.height);
    //set output camera mode
    parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
    //set focous mode
    parameters.setFocusMode(FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    //set flash mode
    parameters.setFlashMode("auto");
    List<int[]> fps = parameters.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange();
    //System.out.println("FPS size: " +fps.size());
    //System.out.println("MAX FPS:"+(fps.get(fps.size()-1)[1])/1000);
    //log min and max camera supported fps
    Log.d("CAMERA", "CAMERA MAX FPS: "+(fps.get(fps.size()-1)[1])/1000);
    Log.d("CAMERA", "CAMERA MIN FPS: "+(fps.get(fps.size()-1)[0])/1000);
    if(camera_fps)
    {
        parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(fps.get(fps.size()-1)[1], fps.get(fps.size()-1)[1]);
    }
    //set camera parameters
    camera.setParameters(parameters);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device are capable of previewing @" + fps.get(fps.size()-1)[1]/1000+"fps!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return camera; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I've got the same problem. `mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);` didn't help. In my activity I've added this to `releaseCamera`:

```
mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
```

and it works now.

Comment: This worked for me. I put it in `onPause` between `mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null)` and `mCamera.release()`.

Comment: What exactly is `mPreview` in this code?  I'm receiving the same error, but don't appear to have any objects of a suitable type to pass to this method.  The only callback I have is a `Camera.PreviewCallback`, not a `SurfaceHolder.Callback` (`mPreview.getHolder()` is your `SurfaceHolder`, right?)

Comment: Something like this:
`private CameraPreview mPreview;`
In onResume:
`mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, preview, null);`

`public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback`

Sorry, it was long ago, don't quite remember.

Answer (score 20):

@ookami.kb solution worked for me too, as well as @srunni commented.

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
        mCamera.release();
    }
}
```

I removed onDestroy method too.

Comment: Why would you remove from OnDestroy too - makes no sense at all!

Answer (score 10):

The docs clearly say that [`camera.release()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#release%28%29) releases all camera resources. After this call camera reference can not be used any more.

If you want to use camera again you have to acquire it via a `open(int)` method.

It's all described in the [camera docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html).

Comment: can you please check the code again? i've add your advice and fixed the rest according to android dev's guideline but still no result

Comment: Still the same error? It clearly says `Method called after release()` and next line `at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(..)`. So you must be calling `setPreviewDisplay()` after `release()`

Comment: in my onResume, i need resume my preview, thus,  using mCamera.open()..., then set all my parameters and preview display surface again, correct? that must have been called after release(). if that's causing the exception, how do i resume it correctly?

Comment: anyway, i've surrounded my setPreviewDisplay(..) with try catch statement, now system will report exception but continue my tasks; i'll see this as a workaround then :) your more than welcome to add anything if you think that's not it :)

Comment: This is not the correct answer.  The problem is fixed with `removeCallback()` as per the other answers.  The docs from google are incomplete.

Answer (score 5):

To Resume correctly, you need to do this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  

    // Get the Camera instance as the activity achieves full user focus
    if (mCamera == null) {
        initializeCamera(); // Local method to handle camera initialization
    }
}



protected void initializeCamera(){
    // Get an instance of Camera Object
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

   // create a basic camera preview class that can be included in a View layout.
    mPreview=new CameraPreview(this,mCamera);

    //add your preview class to the FrameLayout element.
    preview.addView(mPreview);

   //Trigger capturing an image by calling the Camera.takePicture() method.
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // get an image from the camera
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                }
            }
        );
}
```

And also just to remind that in oncreate() do nothing except defining FrameLayout preview and Button captureButton.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    this.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
  Log.e("surfaceDestroyed", "surfaceDestroyed");

}
```

And re initialize the camera in on Resume function.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to okambi's answer.

This is the function messing everything up when you resume:

```
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The try{} is not catching the exception being thrown. Namely that mCamera doesn't exist, and then when it tries to call setPreviewDisplay(holder), there is a crash.

So by removing the callback, this surfaceCreated doesn't get called and avoids the crash.

This is VERY POORLY DOCUMENTED by Google.

Answer (score 1):

I have put

```
mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
```

between.

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
```

and

```
mCamera.release();
```

and it worked for me.

```
 @Override
            protected void onPause() {
                super.onPause();

                this.saveTextEdits();
                try {
                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                    **mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);**
                    mCamera.release();
                    mCamera = null;
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, i fixed it by
- Adding **mCamera = null;** in **surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)** method of **Preview** class.

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

and
- Adding

```
camera = Camera.open();
    camera.startPreview();
    params = camera.getParameters();
    preview.setCamera(camera);
```

in **OnResume()** method of my CameraActivity.

Answer (score 0):

If you got:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewCallback(android.hardware.Camera$PreviewCallback)'
>   on a null object reference

I agree with @ookami.kb - `mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);` is not enough, behind it also add this:

```
mCameraView.getHolder().removeCallback(mCameraView);
```