# android camera release error from PreviewCallback

Tags: android, android-camera

So I've read over the Camera API and couldn't find anything on this. I'm using the Camera to grab frames and it works perfectly, until I try to release the camera. I replicated the error in one sequence of calls:

```
camera = Camera.open();
camera.setPreviewDisplay(getHolder());
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List<Size> ls = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
Size size = ls.get(1);
this.width = size.width;
this.height = size.height;
params.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
camera.setParameters(params);
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
camera.startPreview();
camera.stopPreview();
camera.release();
```

The error I get is

```
03-22 13:31:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(14152): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
03-22 13:31:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(14152):    at android.hardware.Camera.setHasPreviewCallback(Native Method)
03-22 13:31:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(14152):    at android.hardware.Camera.access$600(Camera.java:114)
03-22 13:31:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(14152):    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:545)
03-22 13:31:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(14152):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 13:31:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(14152):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-22 13:31:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(14152):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3684)
03-22 13:31:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(14152):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 13:31:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(14152):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-22 13:31:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(14152):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:845)
03-22 13:31:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(14152):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603)
03-22 13:31:42.592: E/AndroidRuntime(14152):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So whatever is going on is not in one of my functions.
If I comment out the camera.setPreviewCallback(this); then this error does not appear, but I obviously lose my callback, which is the whole point of including the camera in my app.

Comment: I also faced same problem, i fixed it using [http://stackoverflow.com/a/34064944/4531507](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34064944/4531507)

Comment: The general rule is that any camera call can throw a RuntimeException at any time, even if the specific call does not have this exception officially documented. If your test devices never misbehave this way, be assured that some unfortunate superposition of hardware, ROM, and installed software will cause this crash, in either reproducible or irreproducible way.

Answer (score 64):

You have to unset preview callback before `camera.release()`, after `camera.stopPreview()`:

```
camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
```

Otherwise it might get called after camera has been released.

Comment: This worked for me, too.  Other stackoverflow answers mentioned it, but the key for me was that it needed to be done between camera.stopPreview and camera.release().  Thanks!

Comment: If this does not help, try to follow a slightly different advice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13358179/192373

Answer (score 17):

As a side note, a complete `releaseCamera` method looks like:

```
// release Camera for other applications
private void releaseCamera() {
    // check if Camera instance exists
    if (mCamera != null) {
        sPreviewing = false;
        // first stop preview
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        // then cancel its preview callback
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        // and finally release it
        mCamera.release();
        // sanitize you Camera object holder
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it, that's all that is necessary! Just be careful to put it at the right place, because my problem was that I had a second place where I was trying to `stopPreview()` and of course it was crashing..

Comment: @Apostrofix, in order just to stop the camera you might want to create another method if you use it in more than one place or check if 'mCamera' object is null before stopping it.