# Method called after release

Tags: android, android-camera, release

these days i was try to code a custom camera, but there's many bugs i can't figure out. the most serious error log as below.

```
at android.hardware.Camera.setHasPreviewCallback(Native Method) 
at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewCallback(Camera.java:600)  
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()   
at android.hardware.Camera.setHasPreviewCallback(Native Method) 
at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewCallback(Camera.java:600)  
at com.baitian.wenta.customcamera.CameraActivity.cameraRelease(SourceFile:210)  
at com.baitian.wenta.customcamera.CameraActivity.runExceptionHandle(SourceFile:526) 
at com.baitian.wenta.customcamera.CameraActivity.updateFlashStatus(SourceFile:859)  
at com.baitian.wenta.customcamera.CameraActivity.onResume(SourceFile:152)   
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1199)  
at com.qihoo360.mobilesafe.loader.b.callActivityOnResume(SourceFile:123)    
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5280)   
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2629)   
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667)    
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)    
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)   
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)    
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)   
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

it seems the Method wouldn't called after release. i make the camera null everytime when i try to release it, and there is no multithread call.
here is the camera release code:

```
private void cameraRelease() {
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCameraExceptionLog.addLog("Camera release() After", "");
                mCamera = null;
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {

        }
    }
```

here is the camera init code

```
    private void initCamera() {
        try {
            if (mCamera == null) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=        Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
                    mCamera = Camera.open(0);
                } else {
                    mCamera = Camera.open();
                }
                mCamera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onError(int error, Camera camera) {
                        isCanAutoFouce = false;
                        CameraActivity.this.setResult(ERROR_KEY);
                        CameraActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                });
                setFocusAreaDefault();
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            runExceptionHandle(e);
        }
    }
```

Can you help me,thank you .

Comment: It looks like you have two different stack traces running together. Can you clarify the stack trace? (i.e. why is "Method called after release()" in the middle of it?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [method called after release() exception unable to resume with android camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868732/method-called-after-release-exception-unable-to-resume-with-android-camera)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null)` in between `mCamera.stopPreview()` and `mCamera.release()`. This way you cancel any callbacks coming.

I provided a complete `cameraRelease` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30095983/2618036)

Answer (score 0):

I see at least three possible problems with the log and posted code:

1. You might want to [call mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null) after mCamera.stopPreview(); and before mCamera.release()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9835370/2566855).
2. The log seems to refer to a `Camera#setPreviewCallback()` being called from the `cameraRelease()` method, which is not being shown on the posted code. Maybe the actual running code log was of an older version of the posted code.
3. It seems that you reach the `cameraRelease()` code from some sort of error handling. It might be the case that the error that happened to trigger the `cameraRelease()` code could have already released the camera because of some illegal state, hence any call inside this method, such as the `mCamera.stopPreview()` or `mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null)` calls would likely fail if the camera was already released at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. This line is the key line.

`com.qihoo360.mobilesafe.loader.b.callActivityOnResume`

From the log above, the camera permission is disabled by Qihoo 360 mobilesafe. After `Camera.open()`, although it return normally, the camera is released immediately. So you should check and catch the error after `Camera.open()`.

```
try {
     Camera camera = Camera.open();
     if (camera != null) {
         cmaera.getParamters(); // empty operation
     }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrack()
    // oops, finish activity
}
```

As a third-party app, how Qihoo 360 mobilesafe can do like this? How it can perform permission management? This problem confuses me. Does it utilize unknown bug in system to do this?