# app crashes when closing / reopening then pressing button

Tags: android

I'm running eclipse and honestly teaching myself the basics of android programming. I'd figure I would start with a simple flashlight app just so I can get a better understanding of how this works. The app itself works fine and initiates the camera flash.

My problem is when I press the home button, then go back into the app and press the button to turn on the flashlight, the app crashes. I've been reading a lot and i'm guessing it's due to me not having an "onResume" but I may be wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
  import android.hardware.Camera;
  import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import com.pmm.lettherebe.R;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//flag to detect flash is on or off
private boolean isLighOn = false;

private Camera camera;

private Button button;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();;
    }
}




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFlashlight);

    Context context = this;
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    // if device support camera?
    if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        Log.e("err", "Device has no camera!");
        return;
    }

    camera = Camera.open();
    final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (isLighOn) {
                Log.i("info", "torch is turn off!");

                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.stopPreview();
                isLighOn = false;


            } else {

                Log.i("info", "torch is turn on!");
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.startPreview();
                isLighOn = true;

            }

        }
    });

}
   }
```

Here is the logcat error:

> ```
>  07-02 20:32:19.680: D/OpenGLRenderer(14897): Enabling debug mode 0
>  07-02 20:32:21.121: I/info(14897): torch is turn on!
>  07-02 20:32:22.553: I/info(14897): torch is turn off!
>  07-02 20:32:23.363: I/info(14897): torch is turn on!
>  07-02 20:32:23.964: I/info(14897): torch is turn off!
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: I/info(14897): torch is turn on!
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: D/AndroidRuntime(14897): Shutting down VM
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: W/dalvikvm(14897): threadid=1: thread exiting
>  withuncaught           exception (group=0x41b46930)
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method 
>  alled after release()
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):     at
>  android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):     at
>  android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1496)
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):     at
>  com.pmm.lettherebe.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:74)
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):     at
>  android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):     at
>  android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):     at
>  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)     
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):     at
>  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):     at
>  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):     at
>  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):     at
>  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):     at
>  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):     at
>  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):     at
>  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
>  07-02 20:32:29.090: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):     at
>  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>  07-02 20:32:31.222: I/Process(14897): Sending signal. PID: 14897 SIG: 9
> ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [method called after release() exception unable to resume with android camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868732/method-called-after-release-exception-unable-to-resume-with-android-camera)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the `onPause` in your activity is being called, and you're releasing the Camera - this is good. However, you never re-initialize it.

The Android developer guide has [this exact example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html).

Basically, you need to do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (camera == null) {
        initializeCamera();
    }
}
```

Then you move all the camera initialization code from your `onCreate` into a new `initializeCamera` method.

Note you should not initialize the camera in `onCreate`, since it is being done in `onResume` (which is called even on first load).

Comment: I know this is old, but how it would be if the preview is on a fragment?

Comment: I _assume_ (without looking at any code) that this would just plug straight into the fragments `onPause`/`onResume` methods. Looking over this answer it looks like the question asker has edited their question to remove their sample code. That's frankly quite unhelpful to any future viewers (especially considering the answer depends on that context) so I'm going to roll that back.

Comment: Thanks. For some weird reason the "if (camera != null)" line makes my onResume (at the fragment) crash. I'll work it out and post here when I have a solution for this fragment case.