# Parse App crashes after closing and reopening

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have been working on an app that uses parse as cloud client where I execute basic queries.

The app is working fluidly but the problem occurs when I close and reopen the app. When I do that, the app crashes.

After looking for the problem so many times, I found that the app crashes because I was again initializing parse using:

```
Parse.initialize(this, application_id, client_id);
```

which is present in the `onCreate()` function.

So I tried to look any way to close the parse initialization but didn't found any.

It would be quite helpful if anyone can help me in this.

Comment: Do you call Parse.initialize(...) in your Activity onCreate? A better place might be Application onCreate()

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438395/app-crashes-when-closing-reopening-then-pressing-button help you?

Comment: You need to check your logcat in order to see what is the crash.

Comment: @Prasanna I have already tried that. Problem is not with onPause or onResume. The problem is coming when I re-initialize parse.

Comment: @Christoph Can you give me an example?