# Returning from Web Intent, Android camera app stops

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that scans qr codes. Then it displays the result by showing the clickable link for the website. When i click the link I will be redirected to the website but when i click back button on my phone it should return to the app but there is an error. It says the app stopped. I think that I do not have the code that will handle the activity when I return from the website.

can you please help me? What should I do? 
Thanks. :)

```
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Native Method)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Camera.java:519)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at net.sourceforge.zbar.android.CameraTest.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:63)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:605)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:237)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:8019)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1081)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1081)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1081)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1081)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1081)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1497)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1237)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5162)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
03-02 20:58:53.454: E/AndroidRuntime(11165):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Isn't any log to review the details of the error?

Comment: You should post logcat so that we can analyze your error

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868732/method-called-after-release-exception-unable-to-resume-with-android-camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/15358323/1590950

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);   // you need this line
        mCamera.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: it now returns from the website but the camera is not working.

Comment: Not working how? If you don't share the logcat/stacktrace and relevant code you're expecting us to mystically know what's happening...

Comment: there is no camera preview. it is just a black screen.