# Application Crashes when resuming the app

Tags: java, android, onresume

I am creating a simple Flashlight App, but every time I leave the app and reopen it, it crashes. Am I missing something in my code, because I am not sure what, below is an error when it crashes. Please let me know what I need to do in order to fix this resume issue:

```
package com.example.gkvxm.materiallight;

import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dd.CircularProgressButton;

import java.io.IOException;


public class FlashLightActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private boolean isLigtOn = false;

    private Camera camera;

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        SurfaceView preview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.PREVIEW);
            SurfaceHolder mHolder = preview.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();

        if(camera!=null){
            camera.release();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flash_light);

        Context context = this;
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Toast.makeText(FlashLightActivity.this, "Your Device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("err", "Device is not supported");
            return;
        }

        camera = Camera.open();
        final Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();


        final CircularProgressButton circularButton1 = (CircularProgressButton) findViewById(R.id.btnWithText);
       circularButton1.setIndeterminateProgressMode(true);
        circularButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isLigtOn) {
                    turnOffFlash(p);
                    Toast.makeText(FlashLightActivity.this, "Lights Off!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    turnOnFlash(p);
                    Toast.makeText(FlashLightActivity.this, "Lights On!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                if (circularButton1.getProgress() == 0) {
                    simulateSuccessProgress(circularButton1);
                } else {
                    circularButton1.setProgress(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void turnOnFlash(Camera.Parameters p){
        p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

        camera.setParameters(p);
        camera.startPreview();
        isLigtOn = true;
    }
    private void turnOffFlash(Camera.Parameters p){
        p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(p);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isLigtOn = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,int format,int width,int height){

    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
        try{
            Log.i("SurfaceHolder","Setting preview");
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
        Log.i("SurfaceHOlder", "stopping preview");
        camera.stopPreview();
        holder = null;
    }

    private void simulateSuccessProgress(final CircularProgressButton button) {
        ValueAnimator widthAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(1, 100);
        widthAnimation.setDuration(1500);
        widthAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        widthAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                button.setProgress(value);
            }
        });
        widthAnimation.start();
    }

    private void simulateErrorProgress(final CircularProgressButton button) {
        ValueAnimator widthAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(1, 99);
        widthAnimation.setDuration(1500);
        widthAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        widthAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                button.setProgress(value);
                if (value == 99) {
                    button.setProgress(-1);
                }
            }
        });
        widthAnimation.start();
    }


}
```

Error :

```
05-22 03:08:35.646  13909-13909/com.example.gkvxm.materiallight E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gkvxm.materiallight, PID: 13909
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Camera is being used after Camera.release() was called
            at android.hardware.Camera._stopPreview(Native Method)
            at android.hardware.Camera.stopPreview(Camera.java:732)
            at com.example.gkvxm.materiallight.FlashLightActivity.surfaceDestroyed(FlashLightActivity.java:129)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:564)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:238)
            at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:8785)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1164)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1164)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1164)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1164)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1318)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: overrite on Pause() and onResume(). It may help you.

Comment: It may be due to you are releasing camera at onStop and trying to use camera after that in onResume method.Add/or open camera in onResume method too.

Comment: I also faced same problem, i fixed it using [http://stackoverflow.com/a/34064944/4531507](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34064944/4531507)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camera is being used after `Camera.release()` was called. So, looking at the activity lifecycle, you need to open the camera in `onStart()` or in `onRestart()`. So Maybe this code will work fine ...

```
package com.example.gkvxm.materiallight;

import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dd.CircularProgressButton;

import java.io.IOException;


public class FlashLightActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private boolean isLigtOn = false;

    private Camera camera;

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
         camera = Camera.open();
    final Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        SurfaceView preview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.PREVIEW);
            SurfaceHolder mHolder = preview.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();

        if(camera!=null){
            camera.release();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flash_light);

        Context context = this;
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Toast.makeText(FlashLightActivity.this, "Your Device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("err", "Device is not supported");
            return;
        }

        camera = Camera.open();
        final Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();


        final CircularProgressButton circularButton1 = (CircularProgressButton) findViewById(R.id.btnWithText);
       circularButton1.setIndeterminateProgressMode(true);
        circularButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isLigtOn) {
                    turnOffFlash(p);
                    Toast.makeText(FlashLightActivity.this, "Lights Off!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    turnOnFlash(p);
                    Toast.makeText(FlashLightActivity.this, "Lights On!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                if (circularButton1.getProgress() == 0) {
                    simulateSuccessProgress(circularButton1);
                } else {
                    circularButton1.setProgress(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void turnOnFlash(Camera.Parameters p){
        p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

        camera.setParameters(p);
        camera.startPreview();
        isLigtOn = true;
    }
    private void turnOffFlash(Camera.Parameters p){
        p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(p);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isLigtOn = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,int format,int width,int height){

    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
        try{
            Log.i("SurfaceHolder","Setting preview");
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
        Log.i("SurfaceHOlder", "stopping preview");
        camera.stopPreview();
        holder = null;
    }

    private void simulateSuccessProgress(final CircularProgressButton button) {
        ValueAnimator widthAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(1, 100);
        widthAnimation.setDuration(1500);
        widthAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        widthAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                button.setProgress(value);
            }
        });
        widthAnimation.start();
    }

    private void simulateErrorProgress(final CircularProgressButton button) {
        ValueAnimator widthAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(1, 99);
        widthAnimation.setDuration(1500);
        widthAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        widthAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                button.setProgress(value);
                if (value == 99) {
                    button.setProgress(-1);
                }
            }
        });
        widthAnimation.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the Log says `Camera is being used after Camera.release() was called`. So, looking at the [activity lifecycle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/images/android_activity_lifecycle.jpg) you need to open camera in `onStart()` or in `onRestart()`

Answer (score 1):

This exception is because of  `camera.release();` is called in the `onStop()` method of your activity. After releasing the camera instance you are reusing the released instance.

```
 camera = Camera.open();
```

move the above line from `OnCreate()` to `onStart()`

Answer (score 1):

You are releasing the camera instance in onPause() which is correct due to documentation:

> public final void release ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Disconnects and releases the Camera object
>   resources.
>
> You must call this as soon as you're done with the Camera object.

But you also need to re-open it in onResume(), like you do in onCreate, since onCreate() not always is called when you resume the app.

As they state [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#release()):

> Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other
>   applications. Applications should release the camera immediately in
>   onPause() (and re-open() it in onResume()).

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) for more information about the android app lifecycle.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It may be you are `camera.release();` on `onStop()`. And when `surfaceDestroyed` call you have used `camera.stopPreview();`

so `camera` is alredy `release` and you are going to `stopePreview`. thats way you are geting `Camera is being used after Camera.release() was called` this error.

so you have to cange that.

```
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
}
```

and on `surfaceDestroyed`

```
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
    Log.i("SurfaceHOlder", "stopping preview");
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    holder = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with camera class. Use this line onResume()

```
mCameraPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mCameraPreview);
```

and its work now.

Answer (score 0):

I had an app with the same issue,
when I removed "on click listener" inside my on create function, the problem was solved.

I think we should never insert any implementation function or other things inside our onCreate method...

It's better to use onCreate only for declaring and instantiating variables.