# App crashes when image is selected from gallery in custom built camera app

Tags: android

here is the image picker code I'm using:

```
 private void openGallery() {
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);

}
```

and in "onActivityResult" :

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        mImageView.setImageURI(imageUri);


        }

    }
```

So can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong

I get this in logcat:

> 03-16 23:30:00.631 12217-12217/com.example.rafiamansoor.camapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.example.rafiamansoor.camapp, PID: 12217
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
>                                                                                        at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewSurface(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Camera.java:679)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.example.rafiamansoor.camapp.CameraView.surfaceCreated(CameraView.java:46)
>                                                                                        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:666)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:299)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:9370)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1285)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1285)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1285)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1285)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1285)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1285)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1285)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1507)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1230)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6726)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
>                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
>                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

and also the portrait pics are saved in landscape mode so can anyone also tell me how to fix the orientation

Comment: you are probably invoking some method on your camera instance after you call release

Comment: Possible duplicate of [method called after release() exception unable to resume with android camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868732/method-called-after-release-exception-unable-to-resume-with-android-camera)

Comment: thanks but In my code there is onPause and onResume never used and if I remove my Destroy method hen it gives me error. @Kaushal28

Comment: I tried but couldn't be able to know what I.m doing wrong @SarthakMittal

Comment: And also if I remove my camera.release from on destroy then on selecting image from gallery my app does'not crash but the selected image is not displayed instead the camera opens again

Comment: did you tried to debug your code?